# variable not changing according to program

Tags: python, function, variables

I am making a rock, paper, scissor game. I want to increase the player score or the computer score after one of them wins but they aren't increasing.

```
def logic():
    rounds = 1
    computer_score = 0
    player_score = 0
    print(f'computer score: {computer_score}')
    print(f'player score: {player_score}')
    if get_user_token() == 'rock':
        if computer == 'rock':
            wl_label.config(text=f'This Round was a TIE')
            # rounds += 1
            return 'user TIE'
        if computer == 'paper':
            computer_score += 1
            wl_label.config(text=f'You LOST This Round')
            computer_score_label.config(text=f'COMPUTER-{computer_score}')
            # rounds += 1
            return 'user LOST'
        if computer == 'scissor':
            wl_label.config(text=f'You WON This Round')
            player_score += 1
            player_score_label.config(text=f'PLAYER-{player_score}')
            # rounds += 1
            return 'user WON'
        rounds += 1

logic()
```

When I run the `logic()` function and print `player_score` and `computer_score` the variables should change after every win but they remain the same (i.e. 0).

Comment: You are returning a value (i.e. exit) from the function every time you match a condition. To keep the status, consider passing an argument to the function. I don't know if you put `logic()` in the end to do a recursion or something like that, but it simply does not work as you are not passing/receiving anything from your logic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a classic scoping problem. Every time you run `logic()`, then `computer_score` and `player_score` are set to 0.

You are in fact incrementing them, but this is not being displayed because you print the score *before* the increment.

I would do something like this:

```py
computer_score = 0
player_score = 0
rounds = 1

def logic():
    global computer_score
    global player_score
    global rounds
    
    ...

    print(f"computer score: {computer_score}")
    print(f"player score: {player_score}")
```